# Centos7 Stop bloated logging

Tags: logging, centos7, syslog, rsyslog

I have a server with the OS Centos 7 and looking at log file(s) such as the messages log file **("/var/log/messages")** I can see it is primarily filled with entries like the following:

```
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Created slice user-48.slice.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Starting user-48.slice.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 984866 of user apache.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Starting Session 984866 of user apache.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 984868 of user apache.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Starting Session 984868 of user apache.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 984867 of user apache.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Starting Session 984867 of user apache.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Started Session 984869 of user apache.
Aug 29 12:46:01 localhost systemd: Starting Session 984869 of user apache.
Aug 29 12:46:02 localhost systemd: Removed slice user-48.slice.
Aug 29 12:46:02 localhost systemd: Stopping user-48.slice.
Aug 29 12:47:01 localhost kernel: audit_printk_skb: 51 callbacks suppressed
Aug 29 12:47:01 localhost kernel: type=1101 audit(1535543221.712:13161497): pid=45989 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_access,pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="apache" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 29 12:47:01 localhost kernel: type=1101 audit(1535543221.712:13161499): pid=45992 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_access,pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="apache" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 29 12:47:01 localhost kernel: type=1101 audit(1535543221.743:13161500): pid=45991 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_access,pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="apache" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 29 12:47:01 localhost kernel: type=1103 audit(1535543221.749:13161502): pid=45989 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_unix acct="apache" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
Aug 29 12:47:01 localhost kernel: audit: audit_lost=6572998 audit_rate_limit=0 audit_backlog_limit=320
Aug 29 12:47:01 localhost kernel: audit: printk limit exceeded
```

Now, these messages do not look too useful to myself, and thus would like to stop logging this if I am correct.

I would like to know if I am correct in my assumptions on the lack of usefulness of these messages and if so, how would I go about stopping these from being logged?

My **/etc/rsyslog.conf** contents:

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

My syslog:

```
/var/log/cron
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/spooler
{
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
    /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Comment: It appears that a lot of duplicated log entries were already suppressed. I wouldn't worry about it. The visible ones are from apache's cron jobs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The logs such as `Removed slice` and `started/starting session` I do not believe have any use, so unnecessarily logging. I would like these to stop being logged.

Comment: You can remove the cron jobs. That will certainly get rid of them. But, yes, if you have a million of the sessions already, then perhaps there are too many logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't believe removing cron jobs is the correct way. There has to be a way  to change what gets logged and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use CentOS, but it is probably running `systemd` with `journald` and `rsyslog`. Each of these can be configured for logging, but the one closest to the final file `/var/log/messages` is presumably `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. This may have a line such as:

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none   /var/log/messages
```

You can replace `*.info` with a different level, such as `*.warning`. (The levels are: emerg alert crit err warning notice info debug).  You will have to restart the daemon with

```
sudo systemctl status rsyslogd
```

This is all you should need to change, but 
for completeness here are the other 2 configurations that are not usually changed.

With systemd, 
you will probably also be logging in compressed binary files in `/var/log/journal/`. This is configured by file `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` (and others, see `man journald.conf`) which you can edit to add the line, for example,

```
MaxLevelSyslog=warning
```

to reduce the level from the default `debug` which allows all messages to be sent to syslog where they are filtered as discussed above.
You probably need a `sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald` if you make changes to this file.

The file `/etc/systemd/system.conf` (see `man systemd-system.conf`) also has a line for the messages logged from systemd, namely by default

```
LogLevel=info
```

which can be changed too. You might need to reboot to have this file re-read.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you need? The line I mention you need to change is in your rsyslog.conf file.

Comment: Whats the difference between warning and notice

Comment: A program is free to use whatever level it wants for any of its messages, so the difference between warning and notice may be fairly arbitrary. "notice" is for events that are "normal but significant" (according to `man 3 syslog`). I would try `*.notice` first, and if there are still too many messages then try warning. You can also have different levels for each source, so you could try `*.info;systemd.warning;...`

Comment: I will give it ago